# Is it possible to use Retrofit to ping a host

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to ping a host multiple times and calculate an average latency. I want to know if this is possible using retrofit or if I have to use okHttp3 or something else like the system.

Any advice welcome

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "ping a host"? Could you explain in programming terms what you mean by that? For example, do you mean the UDP protocol behind the `ping` utility? Do you mean making an HTTPS request of some endpoint? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am mostly intrested in the latency. I want to ping a host like google.com and count how long it took to reply back. The standard ping that you can find on windows/linux is great but I don't need all that info that comes back. only how long it took to come back

Comment: Retrofit cannot do a UDP `ping` request. Historically, UDP and Java did not get along for some reason, and I don't know if that situation has improved in recent years. Retrofit itself is merely a wrapper over OkHttp, and OkHttp, as the name suggests, performs HTTP(S) requests.